# When introducing multiple files at once, R outputs data from last file only

Tags: r

I am trying to create a code where I introduce multiple text files at once. The files each contain a table, with an example below, and the code below re-organizes each of them. Right now, the variable out.file2 only outputs the adjusted table from the last file the function looped through. I know that the code is correctly looping through each file because if I use print (out.file2) inside the *for* statement, it will output all the adjusted files. However, I need to be able to assign this output to a variable, as I plan to make comparisons across each table. I don't want to redirect any output to a text file because I'd like to do these comparisons in the same script as the one below eventually.

I've tried adjusting the code with function() and lapply() but it didn't make a difference. I've also tried to find a solution from previous questions but was not able to make it work yet. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it!

Sample Table- I realize the format is wonky but that is how it appears when in the text file and introduced into the code, also below. There are 23 columns, each name starting with "col.."

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   col1 col2    col3 col4 col5 col6    
+
|  1      33  6.51    44     16    6.6               
|   col7      col8    col9 col10 col11 col12 
|  2000        95       4   555    33    11        
|  col13 col14    col15 col16 col17  col18      
|  30      ax       53     ax   43    3687       
|  col19 col19    col20 col21 col22                 
|    355     ax     22    34    44                   
|   col23                                                             
|   432                                                              
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Code:

```
 vcffiles = dir(path = "filepath", pattern=".txt") #longneutraldatac
    out.file<- numeric()
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    out.file<- numeric()
    for (i in 1:length(vcffiles)){  #length(vcffiles))
      lines = readLines(vcffiles[i]) 
      ind1 <- seq(1, length(lines), by = 2)
      ind2 <- seq(2, length(lines), by = 2)
      out <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = c(
        paste(lines[ind1], collapse = " "),
        paste(lines[ind2], collapse = " ")
      ))
      out.file2 <- rbind(out.file, out)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"out.file2" is constructed from "out.file" (empty vector) and "out" (the text file) in every iteration of the loop. The content of "out" of the previous iteration is then lost. It should work if you update "out.file" instead of "out.file2" in the loop.

```
vcffiles = dir(path = "filepath", pattern=".txt")#longneutraldatac
out.file<- numeric()

for (i in 1:length(vcffiles)){  #length(vcffiles))
  lines = readLines(vcffiles[i]) 
  ind1 <- seq(1, length(lines), by = 2)
  ind2 <- seq(2, length(lines), by = 2)
  out <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = c(
    paste(lines[ind1], collapse = " "),
    paste(lines[ind2], collapse = " ")
  ))
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, out)
}
```